# System calls in linux kernel

Tags: linux, system-calls, operations

What are three of the basic file operations provided via system calls in the Linux kernel?

Comment: Looks like a homework or an interview question…

Comment: It is a question in a test which i did not know the aswer (just thought i could ask)

Comment: open, read, write, close...etc

Answer (score 2):

I would say the most basic are the four: `open()`, `read()`, `write()` and `close()`.

Comment: I would add `mmap()` to that list. It is quite often used.